# How do i convert minutes to represent hours decimally in sql?

Tags: sql, time, casting

I have *Minutes* 140. Which in hours and minutes becomes 2:20.

In this case i would love to get 2.33.

What i've tried:

```
select cast(140/60 as varchar(8)) + '.' + cast((140 % 60) as varchar(8))
```

Outputs: *2.20*

```
select 140/60
```

Outputs: 2

```
select cast(140/60 as decimal(5,2))
```

Outputs: 2.00

What am i missing?

How do i convert 140 minutes to represent hours decimally?

Comment: you should convert 140 and 60 to float too, select cast(140 as float) / cast(60 as float)

Comment: `select case(140/60 as decimal(5,2))` returns `2.33` just fine for me...

Comment: @hoangnnm Thanks, that did the trick!
    select cast(cast(140 as float) / cast(60 as float) as decimal(5,2))

Comment: 60 need not be float , try below code

Comment: And the reason y u r not getting directly is it takes the numerator data type. You can try second query without converting any number to floaat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about the quick comment, i'll try to explain a little more clearly about this.

By default, Sql will "think" that both your dividend & divisor are INT data type, that's why it returns 2.

If you specify the number with decimal, like this :

```
select (140.00/60.00)
```

now the data type is not int any more, and the result is : 2.3333333

So, you will need to convert one of the data type to float, decimal, numeric(n, n) to get the accurate result :

```
select cast(140 as decimal(5, 2)) / cast(60 as decimal(5, 2))
```

But you still can just convert only dividend or divisor, like this :

```
select 140 / cast(60 as decimal(5, 2))
```

or

```
select cast(140 as decimal(5, 2)) / 60
```

they both gave the same result, becasue the result type is the data type of the argument with the higher precedence, in this case, decimal has the higher precedence than int

you can read more here :

- [Divide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276874%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
- [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258264%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Select convert(decimal(5,2),convert(float,140)/60)
```

or

```
Select cast(140.00/60 as decimal(5,2))
```

Comment: Why do you convert to `float` and then to `decimal`?  Surely both should be `decimal`?

Comment: That's a different question.  `convert(float,140)/60` ***implicitly*** causes a conversion of the `60` in to a `float` due to data-type order of precedence.  Fine.  But why are you converting the `140` to `float` and then converting the result to a `decimal`?  There is no purpose that I can see of using `float` at all.  Why not simply use `CAST(140 as DECIMAL(5,2)) / 60`?  Flipping between `int`, `float` and `decimal` appears overtly inconsistent.

Comment: CAST(140 as DECIMAL(5,2)) / 60 I believe the result is 2.333333 not 2.33. Can u verify yourself and understand y i have provided that . 140 is converted either to float or decilam then / 60 gives 2.333333 which again needs to be converted to decimal(5,2)